# Does the force of releasing the latch of a spring-latch contraption affects the force generated by the spring?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, momentum, interactions, explosions

There is this contraption in my class, where a rod is attached to a latch and a spring. By pulling the latch back behind a piece of metal, the latch is secured, the rod if pulled back and the spring is compressed. Flicking the secured latch upward releases it, which also decompresses the spring, which pushes the rod forward. My question is, if I flick up/release the latch with different force, will it have an effect on the force generated spring, or  the rod?

I'm asking this because I vaguely learn about impulse, where a shorter amount of contact time can affect the something something (I forgot).

Comment: The answer is very dependent on the specifics of the "spring-latch contraption".  If it's designed for laboratory experiments, I'm guessing it would try to minimize such an effect.

Comment: Maybe a sketch would be in order here.